# Cannot get my C# ASP.NET Core MVC Joke application to display my input into the search field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am relatively new to programming and have a job as a programmer now and I have been teaching myself C# and ASP.NET Core MVC and I was working through a tutorial on Youtube and I followed all the instructions but I coded a search field into the application and wanted it to display whatever jokes contained the word that I searched but when I search any word even a word contained in the joke or answer I do not get any results.

I was wondering if there was any way to do it aside from putting it into the model?

Here is my `ShowSearchForm.cshtml` markup:

```
  <h4>Search for a Joke</h4>
  <hr />
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
         <form asp-action="ShowSearchResults">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SearchPhrase" class="control-label"></label>
            <input "SearchPhrase" class="form-control" />           
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" formaction="@Url.Action("ShowSearchResults", new    

---
  { SearchPhrase = SearchPhrase})" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>
 </div>

  <div>
  <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
  </div>
```

I tried to add

```
formaction="@Url.Action("ShowSearchResults", new { SearchPhrase -=    SearchPhrase})"
```

but I am getting an error

> The name 'SearchPhrase' does not exist in the current context

Here is my `JokesController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using JokeWebApp.Data;
using JokeWebApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace JokeWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class JokesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public JokesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Jokes
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return _context.Joke != null ?
                        View(await _context.Joke.ToListAsync()) :
                        Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Joke'  is null.");
        }

        // GET: Jokes/ShowSearchForm
        public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSearchForm()
        {
            return _context.Joke != null ?
                        View() :
                        Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Joke'  is null.");
        }
    
        // Post : Jokes/ShowSearchResults
        public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSearchResults(String SearchPhrase)
        {
            return View("Index", await _context.Joke.Where(j =>
    j.JokeQuestion.Contains(SearchPhrase)).ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Jokes/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Joke == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var joke = await _context.Joke
                                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (joke == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(joke);
        }

        [Authorize]
        // GET: Jokes/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Jokes/Create
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,JokeQuestion,JokeAnswer")] Joke joke)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(joke);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(joke);
        }

        [Authorize]
        // GET: Jokes/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Joke == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var joke = await _context.Joke.FindAsync(id);

            if (joke == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(joke);
        }

        // POST: Jokes/Edit/5
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,JokeQuestion,JokeAnswer")] Joke joke)
        {
            if (id != joke.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(joke);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!JokeExists(joke.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(joke);
        }

        [Authorize]
        // GET: Jokes/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Joke == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var joke = await _context.Joke
                                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (joke == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(joke);
        }

        [Authorize]
        // POST: Jokes/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Joke == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Joke'  is null.");
            }

            var joke = await _context.Joke.FindAsync(id);

            if (joke != null)
            {
                _context.Joke.Remove(joke);
            }
        
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool JokeExists(int id)
        {
            return (_context.Joke?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `Joke` model class:

```
namespace JokeWebApp.Models 
{ 
    public class Joke 
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string JokeQuestion { get; set; } 
        public string JokeAnswer { get; set; } 
        public Joke() { } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: namespace JokeWebApp.Models
{
    public class Joke
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string JokeQuestion { get; set; }
        public string JokeAnswer { get; set; }

        public Joke()
        {
                
        }
    }
}

Comment: Model code in comment above. Forgive my awful post, I will get better with time.

Comment: under your question, click `edit` =)

Comment: `I search any word even a word contained in the joke or answer I do not get any results.` means `ShowSearchResults` action receive the value of `SearchPhrase` but `await _context.Joke.Where(j =>
    j.JokeQuestion.Contains(SearchPhrase)).ToListAsync()` returns null?

Answer (score 0):

`I was wondering if there was any way to do it aside from putting it into the model?` It seems you are confusing about model binding in Asp.Net core MVC. According to the code you provided, you want to pass a string instead of a model from form to backend, Asp.Net core model binding based on the name of property. In `ShowSearchResults` action you want to receive a string named `SearchPhrase`, So here you need to specify the the same `name` property as backend in input tag. Change your code to:

```
<h4>Search for a Joke</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="ShowSearchResults" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="SearchPhrase" class="control-label"></label>
                <input name="SearchPhrase" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Now when you input the search value and click submit button, Backend will receive that value successfully.